# How to protect a private REST API in an AJAX app

Tags: javascript, security, api, rest, node.js

I know that there are many similar questions posted, but none of them refers to an HTML/javascript app where the user can access the code.

I have a private REST API written in nodejs. It is private because its only purpose is to server my HTML5 clients apps (Chrome app and Adobe Air app). So an API key is not a good solution since any user can see the javascript code.

I want to avoid bots creating accounts on my server and consuming my resources.

Is there any way to acomplish this?

Comment: I am not sure if any of the answers satisfied your question. Please kindly share how you approached the problem your described. I am building REST + AJAX based web application that can be used for unregistered users. Like yourself, I want to protect the resources from the bots.

Comment: Logically there really is no way to make an API truly private if it's being called from a web page where anyone can view the source and/or monitor the data that's being sent to the server. To catch bots you have the usual tricks like Captcha but ultimately you need back-end support (WAFs, rapid auto-scaling etc.) to deal with the possibility of automated DDOS type attacks. As long as you detect likely DDOS attacks as early as possible (before making DB connections etc.), it's no different to handling bots attempting to download the page in the first place.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An API key is a decent solution especially if you require constraints on the API key's request origin; consider that you should only accept an API key if the originating web request comes from an authorized source, such as your private domain. If a web request comes from an unauthorized domain, you could simply deny processing the request.

You can improve the security of this mechanism by utilizing a specialized encoding scheme, such as a hash-based message authentication code (HMAC). The following resource explains this mechanism clearly:

http://cloud.dzone.com/news/using-api-keys-effectively

Comment: It's also important to observe that the API key solution works for dozens of other APIs including Google Maps, Flickr, Facebook, etc. The trick is in the implementation.

Comment: I can't control where my users came from , it is a public app. Google maps, Flickr, etc use API keys but I'm no sure if they are worried about who use the keys. I think that I can copy and use any Google maps key (haven't tried it).

Comment: You cannot simply copy a Google Maps API key and use it in another domain, because the Google Maps API ties every generated API key to a specific domain class (ie. mydomain.com), and every request that comes in is checked against the referring URL, and other information encoded in the API key. Again, a typical encoding mechanism is HMAC. API keys would be useless otherwise.

Comment: Referrers can be spoofed though, so I'm not sold on how effective that is: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-appleosx-bsd-curl-command-httpreferer/

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is employ mutually-authenticated SSL, so that your server will only accept incoming connections from your app and your app will only communicate with your server.

Here's the high-level approach. Create a self-signed server SSL certificate and deploy on your web server. If you're using Android, you can use the keytool included with the Android SDK for this purpose; if you're using another app platform, similar tools exist for them as well. Then create a self-signed client and deploy that within your application in a custom keystore included in your application as a resource (keytool will generate this as well). Configure the server to require client-side SSL authentication and to only accept the client certificate you generated. Configure the client to use that client-side certificate to identify itself and only accept the one server-side certificate you installed on your server for that part of it.

If someone/something other than your app attempts to connect to your server, the SSL connection will not be created, as the server will reject incoming SSL connections that do not present the client certificate that you have included in your app.

A step-by-step for this is a much longer answer than is warranted here. I would suggest doing this in stages as there are resources on the web about how to deal with self-signed SSL certificate in Android (I'm not as familiar with how to do this on other mobile platforms), both server and client side. There is also a complete walk-through in my book, Application Security for the Android Platform, published by O'Reilly.

Comment: My web app is pure javascript and HTML, not android

Comment: And this approach still works. Enforce mutually-auth SSL between your app's web server and whatever clients you want to communicate with.

Comment: How can I do that for a standard web browser? Lets say Google Chrome.

Comment: You need to generate a client certificate and load that into your browser's keystore as an Identity Certificate. How you do that is browser-dependent.

Comment: But I can't ask that to my users. I don't think they would know how to do it.